# Use contextmanager to trap instructions for later execution

Tags: python, transactions, contextmanager

I want to achieve a pseudo-db-like transaction using context manager.

Take for example:

```
class Transactor:
    def a(): pass
    def b(d, b): pass
    def c(i): pass

    @contextmanager
    def get_session(self):
        txs = []
        yield self  # accumulate method calls
        for tx in tx:
            tx() # somehow pass the arguments

def main():
    t = Transactor()
    with t.get_session() as session:
        session.a() # inserts `a` into `txs`
        ... more code ...
        session.c(value) # inserts `c` and `(value)` into `txs`
        session.b(value1, value2) # inserts `b` and `(value1, value2)` into `txs`
        ... more code ...
        # non-transator related code
        f = open('file.txt') # If this throws an exception,
                             # break out of the context manager, 
                             # and discard previous transactor calls.
        ... more code ...
        session.a() # inserts `a` into `txs`
        session.b(x, y) # inserts `b` and `(x, y)` into `txs`

    # Now is outside of context manager.
    # The following calls should execute immediately
    t.a()
    t.b(x, y)
    t.c(k)
```

If something goes wrong such as an exception, discard `txs` (rollback). If  it makes it to the end of the context, execute each instruction in order of insertion and pass in the appropriate arguments.

How can to trap the method call for later execution?

And one extra caveat:
If `get_session` is not called, I want to execute the instructions immediately.

Comment: Is there an underlying transaction mechanism or are you making your own?

Comment: @yorodm Making my own bc it's not database related.

Comment: I'm going to write this as a comment since your question has some gray areas to me. You should implement an Unit Of Work over your `Transactor` object and return that instead of `self` in the context manager. In an ideal world, your `Transactor` should be the UoW over something like a database context

Comment: Rollback is not just "throwing away the `txs` list"... if one of those operations fails you have to undo them (or retrieve a snapshot before doing any of those).

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete sample of what you are trying to do, including a rollback scenario? It's not quite clear to me how you expect the roll backs to work.

Comment: @Bakuriu For my use case, it is throwing txs away. The errors and exceptions are from instructions not related to `Transactor`. Methods from `Transactor` are always guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: Think about it this way - if the transactions are like a DB, you can't have an `UPDATE` transaction ran and then if the next line raised an exception just throw the `list` away and call it a day.  The `UPDATE` would still have ran regardless, you'd need to clean that up by `DELETE` or similar types of transactions.  Without knowing the nature of what your "transactions" are, it's hard to gauge.

Comment: It's trivial to store a list of functions you want to run for a later time if nothing fails, but what if the functions themselves cause an exception? Whatever has already been ran would need to be handled.  That's exactly @Bakuriu's point.

Comment: @Idlehands As I mentioned before, that part is irrelevant for my question as my use case doesn't care for that. It just needs to discard the list and is running under the assumption that those don't fail. But yes, I want to know that trivial way of storing a list of functions; preferably using a context manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but to follow the structure you're looking for you'd have to build a temporary transaction class that holds your function queues and execute it after the context manager exits.  You'll need to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), but there are some restrictions though:

1. All the queued up calls must be methods based on your "session" instance.  Anything else gets executed right away.
2. I don't know how you want to handle non-callable session attributes, so for now I assume it'll just retrieve the value.

Having said that, here's my take on it:

```
from functools import partial

class TempTrans:

    # pass in the object instance to mimic
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._queue = []

        # iterate through the attributes and methods within the object and its class
        for attr, val in type(obj).__dict__.items() ^ obj.__dict__.items():
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                if callable(val):
                    setattr(self, attr, partial(self._add, getattr(obj, attr)))
                else:
                    # placeholder to handle non-callable attributes
                    setattr(self, attr, val)

    # function to add to queue
    def _add(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self._queue.append(partial(func, *args, **kwargs))

    # function to execute the queue
    def _execute(self):
        _remove = []

        # iterate through the queue to call the functions.  
        # I suggest catching errors here in case your functions falls through
        for func in self._queue:
            try:
                func()
                _remove.append(func)
            except Exception as e:
                print('some error occured')
                break

        # remove the functions that were successfully ran
        for func in _remove:
            self._queue.remove(func)
```

---

Now onto the context manager (it will be outside your class, you can place it in as a class method if you wish):

```
@contextmanager
def temp_session(obj):
    t = TempTrans(obj)
    try:
        yield t
        t._execute()
        print('Transactions successfully ran')
    except:
        print('Encountered errors, queue was not executed')
    finally:
        print(t._queue)  # debug to see what's left of the queue
```

---

**Usage:**

```
f = Foo()

with temp_session(f) as session:
    session.a('hello')
    session.b(1, 2, 3)

# a hello
# b 1 2 3
# Transactions successfully ran
# []

with temp_session(f) as session:
    session.a('hello')
    session.b(1, 2, 3)
    session.attrdoesnotexist  # expect an error

# Encountered errors, queue was not executed
# [
#   functools.partial(<bound method Foo.a of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0417D3B0>>, 'hello'), 
#   functools.partial(<bound method Foo.b of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0417D3B0>>, 1, 2, 3)
# ]
```

This solution was a bit contrived because of the way you wanted it structured, but if you didn't *need* a context manager and doesn't *need* the session to look like a direct function call, it's trivial to just use `partial`:

```
my_queue = []

# some session
my_queue.append(partial(f, a))
my_queue.append(partial(f, b))
for func in my_queue:
    func()
```